# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'batch:job' - just on a production server

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I know this has been asked many times before but my production tomcat server errors on the batch:job tag. The app runs fine in IntelliJ + the tomcat plugin. The proxy won't allow the server to download any of the schemas but that doesn't seem to affect the bean or tx tags

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<batch:job id="createCsvForJob">
    <batch:step id="createCsvFile">
        <batch:tasklet ref="createCsvForTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

I can download the schemaLocation urls so I don't think there are any weird characters or typos in them. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
">
```

Answer (score 2):

My fix was to include the version number in the schemaLocation, ie

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.0.xsd
```

So I now have

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
">
```

The reason was that because my server couldn't access the internet it needed to use the one that was included in the war file. To find the correct version number I command clicked the xmlns url in IntelliJ

```
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
```

and just read the verison number.

Hope this helps someone else.